# Auto-population of /etc/resolv.conf not working?

Tags: dhcp

I am using Raspbian with a static setup in **/etc/network/interfaces**.
I have read from multiple credible sources that the **/etc/resolv.conf** file is populated by other software on the system, commonly **DHCP**.

To test this, in my **/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf** I tried adding the following

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1 2.2.2.2;
```

I then rebooted my system, expecting to find these addresses as nameservers in my **/etc/resolv.conf**, however this was not the case, both addresses do not exist, and my resolv.conf file is untouched.

I also tried changing the *prepend* parameter to the following

```
supersede domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1 2.2.2.2;
```

After reboot, this also did nothing.

I also tried editing **/etc/network/interfaces** and added the following

```
dns-nameservers 55.55.55.55
```

Again, after reboot, no changes.

Is this intentional behavior? Why isn't resolv.conf being updated/overwritten?

Comment: What is your DHCP client/server configuration? Complete files please.

Comment: And the content of /etc/resolv.conf too.

Comment: What do you mean by "static setup"? Sounds like you're not using DHCP at all.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I used parameters in both dhcpconfig file and */etc/network/interfaces*, /etc/resolv.conf remains untouched.

Comment: does your distribution have the package `resolvconf` installed? (check with `dpkg -l | grep resolvconf`). This guy is the responsible to handle nameservers as parameters of `/etc/network/interfaces`. More information: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#The_resolvconf_program

Comment: @nwildner Note that when the `resolvconf` package is installed, its settings and generated configuration are used *only* if `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` (or `/var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`); if `/etc/resolv.conf` is a regular file, `resolvconf` settings are not taken into account.

Comment: If you are setting a static address in your `interfaces` file, then the DHCP client isn't going to run and configure it, which means it won't set your name servers.... either put a valid name server in `/etc/resolv.conf` or use the proper stanza to set it in your `interfaces` file

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug, which I've reported in the Debian BTS a few hours ago: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=773749

Look at `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` if something has changed.

Comment: I tried *nano /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf*, returns a new file as the file doesnt exist. I read parts of your bug report, which file did you find was being updated on your end? (it sounded like in the report it was done elsewhere)

Comment: How you know OP is using WiCD?

Comment: @Braiam wicd does nothing concerning `/etc/resolved.conf`; it just uses `dhclient`, which has the responsibility of updating `/etc/resolved.conf`, and the OP uses `dhclient` too. I mentioned wicd in my bug report just for the context, but my bug report is against the `isc-dhcp-client` package, which provides `dhclient`.

Comment: Actually, you can't be sure who generates the /etc/resolv.conf file (if it's generated at all). That's my point actually.

Comment: @Braiam `/etc/resolved.conf` should be generated by `dhclient` or something called by `dhclient`, since this is the file where the nameservers are taken from.

Comment: @vinc17 err... no: `head -n 1 /etc/resolv.conf` # **Generated by NetworkManager**.

Comment: @Braiam I do not use NetworkManager. I don't know about the OP, though... But he didn't mention it.