# Dhclient not updating /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: dhcp, resolv.conf, dhclient, resolvconf

On Linux Mint, when I view the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, the first comment states that the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is generated by `resolvconf(8)`.

```
~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
```

To paraphrase the `resolvconf(8)` man page:

> the resolvconf program is run by DHCP clients such as dhclient

I run `dhclient wlan0`.

```
~ $ dhclient wlan0
```

Dhclient should cause the `resolvconf` program to update `/etc/resolv.conf`. The `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` file verifies that I am able to lease the IP address of the nameserver (192.168.0.6).

```
~ $ cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases 
lease {
  interface "wlan0";
  . . .
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.6;
  . . .
}
```

However, the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is not updated. The `/etc/resolv.conf` file has nameserver 127.0.1.1.

```
~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search software.eng.apl
```

There are no nameservers listed in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I am not sure what I am missing here to get the `/etc/resolv.conf` file to update using the nameserver being leased from the DHCP server. The DHCP server is a Linux CentOS machine using DHCPD.

Comment: Is `/etc/resolv.conf` a file or a symlink?

Comment: It looks like `/etc/resolv.conf` is symbolically linked to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. Both files are identical. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll chase this and see if it turns into an answer to the problem.

Comment: With `nameserver 127.0.1.1`, you are running some kind of nameserver or DNS proxy yourself. That proxy in turn will use the nameserver provided by `dhclient`. If you really want this to be visible in `resolv.conf`, disable your DNS proxy.

Comment: Possibly the same issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175526/auto-population-of-etc-resolv-conf-not-working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mint and other modern distros ship with `mdns` by default, which wraps the regular public DNS with a local "decentralized" wrapper which enables zeroconf support for your local network. Basically, a local DNS server resolves names in the local network it has discovered, then falls back to the (now proxied) public DNS for public Internet resolution, i.e. for names outside of your local network.

In so many words, your `resolv.conf` is correct and appropriate for this scenario, and if `mdns` has problems accessing your ISP's nameserver, you should look inside *its* configuration - though of course, if you don't care about zeroconf support, disabling `mdns` (and then probably also Avahi) lets you manage `resolv.conf` in the traditional fashion.

See also e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToZeroconf

Comment: Fascinating. Thank you very much for sharing this intel around `mdns`. I sure am glad there is a logic reason for this behavior. I apologize, I do not yet have enough reputation to up-vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`
edit the line by uncommenting `#prepend domain-name-server`

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?

Comment: using `prepend domain-name-server` allows you to add custom domain name servers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as described in the OP but none of the previous answers worked for me. I'm running Linux Mint 18 and I discovered this problem when trying to use networking features inside a docker container. Docker was expecting to resolve DNS values from `/etc/resolv.conf`. But since the only nameserver listed was 127.0.1.1, docker networking was unsuccessful.

I found **[another solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/627900/182335)** on askubuntu that worked for me. I'm posting it here as a cross reference in case it helps someone.

---

NetworkManager is the program which (via the resolvconf utility) inserts address 127.0.1.1 into resolv.conf. NetworkManager inserts that address if and only if it is configured to start an instance of the dnsmasq program to serve as a local forwarding nameserver. That dnsmasq instance listens for queries at address 127.0.1.1.

If you do not want to use a local forwarding nameserver then configure NetworkManager not to start a dnsmasq instance and not to insert that address. In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq`

`sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq
```

and restart the NetworkManager service.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

In this mode, NetworkManager updates /etc/resolv.conf (still via resolvconf) to include the nameserver addresses NetworkManager has for active connections.

If you want to disable the resolvconf mechanism for updating resolv.conf and just use a static resolv.conf file, do the following.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf  # Delete the symbolic link
sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf   # Create static file
```