# Disable systemd-resolved to free up port 53 and use DNS servers provided by dhcp

Tags: dns, dhcp, elementary-os, systemd-resolved, pi-hole

I will be running a Pi-hole server in a docker container, so I have freed up port 53 by setting`DNSStubListener=no` in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and restarting `systemd-resolved`.

This has freed up port 53, but now DNS doesn't work. I get `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Looking at Network Settings from the desktop, I see 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8 as the DNS servers assigned by DHCP as currently configured, but how do I get my system to use these?

**UPDATE1:**
/etc/resolv.conf has this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search domain.local
```

Comment: What does `/etc/resolv.conf` say?

Comment: @mtak added above

Answer (score 0):

The DNS servers assigned through DHCP will used to configure `resolved`. The rest of the system uses whatever is configured in `/etc/resolv.conf` to resolve addresses. `resolv.conf` is pointing to `127.0.0.53`, which doesn't work anymore, because you disabled `resolved`.

Change `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to active DNS servers:

```
domain domain.local
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

---

Edit: on how to use DHCP assigned DNS servers instead of setting them manually, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453122/52365

Comment: so if I use a browser to open a local URL (hosted in Docker or another system) which DNS entry is used? Same for `curl` and `nslookup`?

Comment: For a browser specifically, it depends on whether it uses DNS-over-HTTPS. But yeah, in general all applications use the same resolving mechanism. Review https://zwischenzugs.com/2018/06/08/anatomy-of-a-linux-dns-lookup-part-i/ for details, because there are some extra layers in there.